# Delphi: Invalid typecast with Move

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am installing an old component pack TSCap32 and get error `Invalid typecast` in multiple location with `Move` command.

```
var
   pCopiedDib: PChar;
...
Move(pOrigDibBmi^, TByteArray(pCopiedDib^)[0], BmiSize);
```

The unit itself declare TByteArray like bellow:

```
type
  TByteArray = array[0..0] of Byte;
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What is `pOrigDibBmi` declared as? Also `PChar`?

Comment: Does `PByteArray = ^TByteArray; ... ... PByteArray(pCopiedDib)^, ` work?

Answer (score 2):

The cast that you are using requires that the `TByteArray` and `pCopiedDib^` types have the same size. They do not: `TByteArray` has size 1, and `pCopiedDib^` has size 2. Thus the compiler rejects your code because it is not valid.

The code was presumably originally written for pre-Unicode Delphi where `PChar` is an alias for `PAnsiChar`. In that scenario the code compiles. Now, you use a Unicode Delphi and `PChar` is an alias for `PWideChar`, and hence the types have different size.

Exactly how to fix your code is unclear. If you define `pCopiedDib` as `PAnsiChar` then your code will compile, but whether or not it will work is a different matter altogther. I suggest that you study this code further now that you know the cause of the error.